# Update or save records from instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 4 with GraphQL API.

I'm getting some inputs via an object, based on which I'm finding or initializing new ActiveRecord objects that I want to save later.

Sample input is:

```
[
  {:id=>"192", :internalId=>128, :title=>"Editing"},
  {:internalId=>130, :title=>"New"}
]
```

As you can notice, some of the records already exist and have an ID, we need to update those. And the rest we need to save as new records.

Then I have a method that goes through those post values:

```
def posts=(value)
  @posts = value.map do |post|
    init_post(post)
  end
end

def init_post(post)
  Post.find_or_initialize_by(
    id: post[:id],
    title: post[:title],
    internal_id: post[:internalId],
  )
end
```

That will return two instances of the Post model:

```
[#<Post id: 192, title: "Editing", internal_id: 128, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Post id: nil, title: "New", internal_id: 130, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

Finally, I want to save both records:

```
def save_posts
  posts.each(&:save)
end
```

Which will return:

```
"#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '192' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `posts` ..."
```

So how do I make sure the instances with ID just update the existing record, and the rest just save as new ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can find, change/create and save it at once

```
Post.find_or_initialize_by(id: post[:id]).tap do |record|
  record.title = post[:title]
  record.internal_id = post[:internalId]
  record.save
end
```

Comment: True. I found out what the problem was though. The two objects I was getting back were new ones, the one with the ID was not the one that exists in the database. Therefore I just performed `find_or_initialize_by` by ID and then `assign_attributes` to those objects, which later I'm updating (I'm running the save method in a transaction, that's why I needed it separately). Thanks for this though, I upvoted!